# how to set ftp in azure vm windows server 2012

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2012, azure

I created an azure vm and installed filezilla server to it. I could not get list of my directory. I search to serverfault and i find i must set an end point for `port 6000` and allow this port in windows firewall, and in filezilla server I must use a custom range in pas if mode to `6000-6000` I set these in filezilla server and restart my vm and after restart I don't find problem and I could get my directory listing but after 2 days, when I worked via ftp, I get error :

```
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (100,76,182,65,23,112)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:      Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

And now, I can not work with ftp for directory listing and i restart my vm sometimes but my problem isn't resolved.

Comment: I can at least confirm that your FileZilla is using the correct port, as `23*256 + 112 = 6000`. And your control port is accessible, as you get a response with a port request. So the problem is either with your server firewall, or your azure endpoints for the 6000 port. Review your setup [against this guide](https://huberyy.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/set-up-a-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-virtual-machine-with-filezilla-no-coding/).

Comment: Can you enable logging in FileZilla and show us the log with timestamps? We need to know what is an interval between the `MLSD` and the `425` response. Is it immediate or with delay?

Comment: i get this error:

Comment: Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,10,23,112)
Command: MLSD
Error: The data connection could not be established: ENETUNREACH - Network unreachable
Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"... Command: CWD / Response: 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory. Command: PWD Response: 257 "/" is current directory. Command: TYPE I Response: 200 Type set to I Command: PASV Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (100,76,182,65,23,112) Command: MLSD Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/" Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Comment: how can enable log?

Comment: hi all, i set end point to 60000 and set filezilla to 60000 and desable windows firewall but don't solve my problem

Comment: hi, if you can, please help, i set all port correctly in inbound and outbound and in endpoint but don't work!

Answer (score 2):

This page describes the prerequisites and steps to follow for creating a passive FTP server on a Windows Server 2012 VM in Azure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2013/12/13/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm.aspx

For Filezilla Server, make sure the ports you configure in FileZilla correspond with the endpoints you configure.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Answers that are basically just links are not really welcome on SF, as there is no control over it and the answer becomes useless when the content gets removed. You should add the relevant parts in the answer and keep the link for more details. See the [answer] page in the help center.